# Wrapping Prisma calls with dynamic arguments

Tags: typescript, prisma

I do have a mono repo and want the data layer to be a completely separate package, so I'm currently extracting all data-related stuff to this package. Unfortunately types do cause some issues for me:

```
(async () => {
  async function getTasks<T extends Prisma.TaskFindManyArgs>(
    args?: Prisma.SelectSubset<T, Prisma.TaskFindManyArgs>
  ) {
    return prisma.task.findMany<T>({
      where: {
        status: TaskStatus.Pending,
      },
      ...args,
    });
  }

  function foo(tasks: TaskWithUserAndItem[]) {
    return tasks;
  }

  const tasks = await getTasks({ include: { user: true, item: true } });

  foo(tasks); // doesn't work, since tasks is `Task[]` and not `TaskWithUserAndItem[]`
})();
```

`TaskWithUserAndItem` is a custom type that requires the `Task` to include `User` and `Item` (by adding `include: { user: true, item, true }` to `findMany`).

Unfortunately, if TypeScript `strict` is mode enabled the return of `getTasks` is invalid according to TypeScript with the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ select?: T["select"] | undefined; include?: T["include"] | undefined; where: T["where"] | { status: "Pending"; }; orderBy?: T["orderBy"] | undefined; cursor?: T["cursor"] | undefined; take?: T["take"] | undefined; skip?: T["skip"] | undefined; distinct?: T["distinct"] | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectSubset<T, TaskFindManyArgs>'.   Type '{ select?: T["select"] | undefined; include?: T["include"] | undefined; where: T["where"] | { status: "Pending"; }; orderBy?: T["orderBy"] | undefined; cursor?: T["cursor"] | undefined; take?: T["take"] | undefined; skip?: T["skip"] | undefined; distinct?: T["distinct"] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof T]: key extends keyof TaskFindManyArgs ? T[key] : never; }'.
```

Disabling `strict` mode does work, but obviously can't be the correct way.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I responded on this GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/19501